# Shortest path in a graph using adjacency list

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

How can I write an algorithm for finding the shortest path from one node to another in a graph using adjacency list and return a max value if no path exists?
Do I use Dijkstra's algorithm and modify it to find the path?

Comment: isn't this exactly dijkstra's algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Traverse the graph according to Dijkstra's algorithm and keep track of each current path while you go.